# Contains method not working mongodb c# driver linq

Tags: mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Is linq contains extension method working for mongodb c# driver?.I am using 2.2 version of driver, and it is giving me exception like below:

Unsupported filter: Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DataBO]).Select({document}{Value})).

Comment: Thanks @LuisSieira. But it is giving me exception when I am using contains method.

Comment: Contains supported in 2.2.